# Laravel Axios.put() example

Tags: laravel, axios

I am new to `laravel` and I am trying to update a record using `aixos`. I managed to retrieve records using `GET`, but I can't seem to get `PUT/PATCH` right.. 
Please help..

```
makeBid(){

axios.put('http://127.0.0.1/myapp/public/api/bid/'+this.itemID,{
NewBidMade:this.NewBidMade
})
.then((response) => {
console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error){
console.log(error);
});
}
}
```

**this is my route**

```
Route::put('bid/{itemID}','CategoriesController@makeBid');
```

**incase it relevant, this is the error I'm currently getting**

```
app.js:13797 PUT http://127.0.0.1/myapp/public/api/bid/8 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:13797
xhrAdapter @ app.js:13631
dispatchRequest @ app.js:35761
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:35217
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:35237
wrap @ app.js:13420
makeBid @ 8:328
click @ VM6640:3
invoker @ vue.js:2029
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.js:1828
8:338 Error: Request failed with status code 500
at createError (app.js:13822)
at settle (app.js:35289)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:13696)
```

Comment: Have you included csrf_token in the request? Laravel requires you to add the csrf token to put/patch requests. See here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

Comment: i have csrf_token in my layout

Comment: @DavidMachara this error is because of PHP code\

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: An 500 error means there is an error in your PHP code.  (It's a server error, not a client error)  Preview the response in  your developer console or look in the logs for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my controller.. turns out i had an error in my controller which led to 500 (Internal Server Error).

thanks for the feedback